# iPhone 5s aware of location even with no cellular service?

Tags: iphone, cellular-data, geolocation

I live in USA and took my VZW iPhone 5s to Scotland; I never purchased a SIM card to use there. I noticed that my iPhone pictures uploaded to Flickr have accurate location data associated with each picture. Example, I was walking around Edinburgh and taking pictures without WiFi/cell connection, but the images still display accurate location of where I took images.

How is that possible?

Comment: Even if you are not connected to a WiFi, there is still the cellular (telephone) towers somewhere in Edinburgh that can be used to determine your Location. If you turn on the Airplane mode, then no more location.

Answer (score 3):

an iPhone has GPS - see [Understanding privacy and Location Services on iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch with iOS 8](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203033)

**About location precision or accuracy**
Depending on your device and available services, Location Services uses a combination of cellular, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, and GPS to determine your location. If you're not within a clear line of sight to GPS satellites, your device can determine your location using crowd-sourced Wi-Fi5 and cell tower locations or iBeacons.

Apps that can show your location on the screen, including Maps, show your current (approximate) location using a blue marker. If your location can't be determined precisely, you'll see a blue circle around the marker. The size of the circle shows how precisely your location can be determined—the smaller the circle, the greater the precision.

When Location Services is active, a black or white arrow icon appears in the status bar.

Maps, directions, and location-based apps depend on data services. These data services are subject to change and might not be available in all geographic areas, resulting in maps, directions, or location-based information that might be unavailable, inaccurate, or incomplete. Compare the information provided on the device to your surroundings and defer to posted signs to resolve any discrepancies.